# アルファベット-数字-数字 の構成以外の文字列を抽出したい

Tags: 正規表現

以下のようなテキストがある時に、

```
A-7-2
D-1-5
D-1-5
A-1
D-1-5,A-2-5
G-5-21,B-3,A-2-5
```

「アルファベット-数字-数字」以外（ここでは `A-1` と `B-3`）のみが抽出されるようにしたいです。
どのような正規表現を用いれば良いでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: テキストを行ごとに解釈したと思うと、5行目は「アルファベット-数字-数字-,アルファベット-数字-数字」になっているので「アルファベット-数字-数字」以外になり、抽出されてしまいます。何か条件を忘れてらっしゃいませんか？

Comment: nekketsuuuさん、ご回答いただきありがとうございます。
そして、大変失礼しました。

「,」で区切っているものも「アルファベット-数字-数字」に該当するというのが追加条件になります。

A-7-2
D-1-5
D-1-5
A-1
D-1-5,A-2-5
G-5-21,B-3,A-2-5

例えば上記の文字列の場合、「A-1」と「B-3」が抽出される正規表現はございますでしょうか？
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: GNU grep の PCRE(Perl Compatible Regular Expressions)オプションを使うと、`grep -Po '[A-Z]-[0-9](?=(,|$))' data.txt` などと書くこともできます。

Comment: metropolisさん、ご回答いただき、ありがとうございます！
突然正規表現を適用して作業しなくてはいけなくなり、試行錯誤していたのですが、一般のテキストエディットを使っていたため（miというエディット）、こちらの環境がよろしくないことに気づきました。。まずは環境を整え、再度チャレンジしてみます。
ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1):

1)カンマ(`,`)区切りのデータを考慮しない場合

nekketsuuuさんのご指摘どおり、以下のような単純な文字列抽出では

```
cat テキストファイル | egrep -v '^[A-Z]-[0-9]-[0-9]$'
```

5行目の`D-1-5,A-2-5`も抽出されてしまいます。

2)カンマ(`,`)区切りの行のすべての項目が条件に合致したときは抽出しない場合

```
cat テキストファイル | gawk '
{
    patern = "^[A-Z]-[0-9]-[0-9]$"
    split($0, a, ",")
    hit = 0;
    for(i in a){
        if(match(a[i] , patern)){
            hit = 1
        }
    }
    if(!hit){
        print $0
    }
}
'
```

実行環境は以下です。
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS　
※WSL下です
gawk GNU Awk 4.1.4
egrep grep (GNU grep) 3.1
bash GNU bash, バージョン 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: akira ejiriさん、ご回答いただき、ありがとうございます。
正規表現に触れるのが初めてで、試行錯誤しながら勉強しています。。
1)については、理解できるのですが、2)が私の理解では及ばず...
打ち込んでみたのですが、hitせずになってしまいました。。
これを機にもっと勉強していきたいと思います。ありがとうございます！

Comment: 回答に実行した環境を追記しました。環境が違う場合は異なる結果になるかもしれません。

Comment: akira ejiriさん、環境を教えてくださり、ありがとうございます。
お恥ずかしい話ですが、ご提示いただいた環境自体がわからない状況で、こちらは一般のテキストエディットにて作業しておりました。
まずは環境を整え、そこから改めて色々と勉強しチャレンジしていきたいと思います。ご助言いただきましたのに、こちらの力が及ばず本当に申し訳ございません。
色々とありがとうございました！